# Map with enums autocasting to value

Tags: typescript

I would like to make a mapper to easily get the function to draw a shape.

For now, I have a problem inside the mapper and I don't see how to fix it.

```js
enum ShapeType {
  POLYGON = 'polygon',
  RECTANGLE = 'rectangle'
}

interface Polygon {
  type: ShapeType.POLYGON;
  points: Array<[number, number]>;
}

interface Rectangle {
  type: ShapeType.RECTANGLE;
  points: [[number, number], [number, number]];
}

type Shape = Polygon | Rectangle;

const mapper: Record<ShapeType, (shape: Shape) => void> = {
  // Argument of type 'Shape' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Polygon'
  [ShapeType.POLYGON]: (shape) => drawPolygon(shape),
  // Argument of type 'Shape' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Rectangle'
  [ShapeType.RECTANGLE]: (shape) => drawRectangle(shape)
};

const drawPolygon = (toDraw: Polygon): void => {}
const drawRectangle = (toDraw: Rectangle): void => {}

const toDraw: Array<Shape> = [];
toDraw.forEach((shape) => mapper[shape.type](shape));
```

I also need to support the behavior inside `toDraw.forEach` where `mapper[shape.type](shape)` is accepted.

Comment: `mapper` is not of the type you annotated it to be.  You should make a more accurate type instead, possibly as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w2131W). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I need to see a [mre] in the question itself before I can suggest anything.  Keep in mind, though, that it's not generally acceptable to expand the scope of a question to ask about the next issue you hit after resolving the original one.  Such followup questions belong in new posts.  Shall I answer the question as-is? Or do we need to expand the scope of this one (and if so, will you [edit] the question to demonstrate)?

Comment: When I use it, I have an error saying _The intersection 'Polygon & Rectangle' was reduced to 'never' because property 'type' has conflicting types in some constituents_

Comment: So you've decided to expand the scope in response to having your original problem fixed. That's disappointing.  Still, if that's your choice, please [edit] the issue so the code is in your question as plaintext, including any relevant code from comments (you can't just say "@jcalz solution" because comments can disappear at anytime). If all you have is a playground link then it doesn't count as a [mre] because we can't require people navigate away from Stack Overflow to see the relevant code.

Comment: (See prev comment, please) The new approach is going to look like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wXgj8W) which is a significant refactoring. I'd write up an answer but I'm very concerned that you'll immediately change the question to focus on some subsequent problem to invalidate my suggestion.  How shall we proceed here?

Comment: This is great! It's not that I wanted to change scope, I just wanted a problem fixed.

Comment: Could you [edit] like I asked?  Or if you don't mind, I'll do it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. If you don't mind, I cleaned it up so that it reads like a single question and not a two-stage question that responds to a suggestion midway through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mapper` type isn't accurate. `Record<ShapeType, (shape: Shape) => void>` means that each method must accept an arbitrary `Shape`.  With that type, it should be completely valid to call `mapper[ShapeType.POLYGON](rectangle)` or `mapper[ShapeType.RECTANGLE](polygon)`, so the compiler is warning you that you can't assume that `shape` is a `Polygon` or that `shape` is a `Rectangle`.  You could try to fix that by adding some runtime check, like

```
const mapper: Record<ShapeType, (shape: Shape) => void> = {
  [ShapeType.POLYGON]: (shape) => {
    if (shape.type !== ShapeType.POLYGON) throw new Error("NO!");
    drawPolygon(shape)
  },
  [ShapeType.RECTANGLE]: (shape) => {
    if (shape.type !== ShapeType.RECTANGLE) throw new Error("NO!");
    drawRectangle(shape)
  }
};
```

but now there's not much point in having a `mapper` at all; you might as well just have a single shape handler like

```
const handler = (shape: Shape) => {
  switch (shape.type) {
    case ShapeType.POLYGON: return drawPolygon(shape);
    case ShapeType.RECTANGLE: return drawRectangle(shape);
  }
}
```

And then your `toDraw.forEach()` simply becomes:

```
const toDraw: Array<Shape> = [];
toDraw.forEach((shape) => handler(shape));
```

---

If, for some reason, you really want to dynamically look up handlers in a `mapper`, then you will need to significantly refactor your types and operations, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109). It involves writing a "basic" key-value interface and then expressing everything as [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) [indexes into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) that interface, or into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over that interface.  That allows the compiler to "see" the abstract relationship between `mapper[shape.type]` and `shape` when `shape` is generic.

Here's the basic mapping interface

```
interface ShapeLookup {
  [ShapeType.POLYGON]: {
    points: Array<[number, number]>;
  };
  [ShapeType.RECTANGLE]: {
    points: [[number, number], [number, number]];
  }
}
```

Now you can write `Shape` as a generic "distributive object type" (as coined in ms/TS#47109):

```
type Shape<K extends ShapeType = ShapeType> =
  { [P in K]: { type: P } & ShapeLookup[P] }[K]
```

So `Shape<ShapeType.POLYGON>` is equivalent to your `Polygon`, and `Shape<ShapeType.RECTANGLE>` is equivalent to your `Rectangle`.  Indeed, assuming you still want them, you can recover your original `Polygon` and `Rectangle` interfaces from those:

```
interface Polygon extends Shape<ShapeType.POLYGON> { }
interface Rectangle extends Shape<ShapeType.RECTANGLE> { }
```

And `Shape` with no generic type argument is equivalent to `Shape<ShapeType>`, which is the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) equivalent to `Polygon | Rectangle`, just like before.

Now we can write the type of `mapper` as a mapped type over `ShapeType`:

```
const mapper: { [K in ShapeType]: (shape: Shape<K>) => void } = {
  [ShapeType.POLYGON]: (shape) => drawPolygon(shape), // okay!
  [ShapeType.RECTANGLE]: (shape) => drawRectangle(shape) // okay!
};
```

That works because the compiler sees that the method for `ShapeType.POLYGON` accepts a `Shape<ShapeType.POLYGON>` which is a `Polygon`, which is what `drawPolygon` accepts.  And similarly for `ShapeType.RECTANGLE`.

Now, whenever you want to write `mapper[shape.type](shape)`, you'll want `shape` to be *generic*, of a type like `Shape<K>`.  This works well inside of [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) because you can make the callback a generic function like this:

```
const toDraw: Array<Shape> = [];
toDraw.forEach(<K extends ShapeType>(
  shape: Shape<K>) => mapper[shape.type](shape) // okay!
);
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-EQYBgr3xzNZuRkKSc2AwDh++dtUW+ZZzgpQU5nMcxLPjPuMy6gq-XKE3RcmwN3lpQVZf-lrEKhm7t33b2BUAAiNopD+OhEiklLUt2b4fvWX42veQLTAo2L-kBBYIhMSHlhBVIotBTwHp+8SAcBKCVNUdQYrSBwPHwaE2pkITIsYSBMNiu5Bk2LbBLuOZDOA0DwGMiJhC4yK8HwNB0MezLBoIbJ5PYyjbjo+hFGemzKU4xbAt4gz+O+QojGJs5LCIKgqAA1hgcDyYyc4KopHIpBOVC7GUFRVDUDRnA4px3D0-Qus+DlLPOmm+q5ubFFSewpIcfkBdcPSXEltwpd0dGVr4RmShitQANLUMQ2A0CiMCyZGcqOWwtJFGQBwCMZKCFX6jUvCBL4oAAZMeFnWbZ9QCN0L71G1RmlMEpmCKpPxQKV5WVQVHosoqeT8jBxllaMyAAg+0wLWVzbLfi6K1aeZjepsm1DEZdYNjCcBwq5BzFYEVVsH6HbHkVvS8mSkH4T49gTmFsZZOtLkjk6QbfnNu5uvw4MnqsV0JsY30BrDfK3ghWElruvg1kRcF4wWoE-ChDEYbNXxgbhUG441r4PfBBaISWf6kbTnPAuBFJ4QR93ETTGpeZR51LDR9TZSR6EakxLFsdiRUlcdFWfVAvQ-QVhX-UGT1wvU2Msi83R8aCPhAA)